# Get one NSArray

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, restkit

I was wondering how to **combine two `array`'s into one `array`**.

I want the combined `tableView` to show the most recent.

I will post any extra code or help as necessary, **thanks so much!**

Comment: Is the content of `iArray` and `hArray` of the seme type (I mean does them have `Feed` objects)? Do you need to put the content of `iArray` first, and the the content of `hArray` in that order? Else, you could use a `NSMutableArray`, where you use `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` to it, or at the object manually (a simple for loop should be enough).

Comment: @Reez i found this mistake in your code, in the else part of tableview:cellForRowAtIndexpath method
// API 2
        Data *dataLocal = [iArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - headlinesArray.count];

here instead of headlinesArray.count you should be using hArray.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the complexity in this question is that the data is coming from two different sources asynchronously.  Get our arms around that and we've got the problem under control.  My suggestion differs from the others in that it aims to take care of the multiple asynch sources right away, leaving simpler code in all the other areas.

The way to handle two asynch sources is to serialize them with a nested completion. Here, I just took your posted code and factored it into two methods, one for each api.  Each takes a success and failure block matching the object manager's interface...

```
- (void)loadOneWithSuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                   failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

    NSString *apikey = @kCLIENTKEY;
    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"apikey" : apikey};
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1/n/?limit=4&leafs=%@&themes=%@", leafAbbreviation, themeID];

    [self.eObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:queryParams success:success failure:failure];
}

- (void)loadTwoWithSuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                   failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

    NSString *path = @"v1/u/2/m/recent/?client_id=e999";
    [self.iObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:success failure:failure];
}
```

Now we can make loadMedia do what we need, which is to load from each api, combine and sort as a single model.  Declare an `NSMutableArray` property called `combinedModel`.  Other answers have suggested this as tableDataList or contentArray.  The key difference in my suggestion is to take care of the combination as part of a combined fetch.

```
- (void)loadMedia {

    self.combinedModel = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self loadOneWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult];

        // here's the trick.  call API2 here.  Doing so will serialize these two requests
        [self loadTwoWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

            [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult];
            [self sortCombinedModel];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
        }];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Now only two problems remain (1) sorting an array of heterogenous objects, (2) rendering heterogenous objects in a table view.  First sort:

```
- (void)sortCombinedModel {
    [self.combinedModel sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *dateA, *dateB;
        dateA = ([a isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)a).published : ((Data *)a).created_time;
        dateB = ([b isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)b).published : ((Data *)b).created_time;
        return [dateA compare:dateB];
    }];
}
```

Now for the table, `self.combinedModel` is the new model for the table view.  All the datasource methods should refer to it.  cellForRowAtIndexPath: should behave just like the sort:.  In a nutshell...

```
id model = self.combinedModel[indexPath.row];
if ([model isKindOfClass:[Feed self]) {
    Feed *feed = (Feed *)model;
    // configure cell with feed
} else {
    Data *data = (Data *)model;
    // configure cell with data
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for such a great+specific+detailed answer.  Quick question, where am I using `sortedArray` in here?  Is it under the `// configure cell with feed/data` part, or somewhere else?

Comment: If so, do I need to create a property for it then?

Comment: That's my bad.  I think you can/should replace the model with the sorted array.  Please see the edit.  Now that sort method assigns the sorted array to the combinedModel.

Comment: Only problem with that I'm seeing is that I'm getting a warning on `self.combinedModel = [self.combinedModel sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *dateA, *dateB;` saying that "Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from NSArray."  If I try to change `combinedModel` to just an `NSArray` then I get 2 errors in the `loadMedia` method.  What should I do for that warning?

Comment: Oh sorry again.  Please leave the property as mutable and see my edit.  The mutable array has it's own destructive variety of the sort method.  Also, please remember to reference only that combined array in your datasource methods, e.g. like numberOfRowsInSection should answer combinedModel.count.

Comment: Ok gotcha understand that now.  I'm still getting all blank cells in the view controller, I created a Gist with all of my actual updated VC code, am I missing something when you look at it?  https://gist.github.com/lllovesmatt/67e009f09abdf92f8f7c

Comment: (I used you're code verbatim except swapped `mappingResult` out for `hArray` and `iArray`)

Comment: One question is in the `sortCombinedModel` method if I need to use `Data self` instead of `Feed self` in `dateB` ... or should I use what you had where `Feed self` gets used for both `dateA` and `dateB`?

Comment: I think the code I posted is correct.  If the a object is a feed, treat it as a feed, else treat it as a data, same for the b object.

Comment: `return combinedModel.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns an array with `0 objects` though, so I'm not sure why that would be?

Comment: Can you nslog what gets added in the success blocks of the network calls?

Comment: `Success 1: <__NSStackBlock__: 0x7fff5fbfc508>` and `<__NSStackBlock__: 0x7fff5fbfdd38>` is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I can see that their are 4 objects coming back from API1, and 20 objects coming back from API2, which is right on the money.

Comment: So you see those 24 objects get added to the combinedModel?  After addObjectsFromArray, do you see that NSLog(@"%@", self.combinedModel) contains the objects?

Comment: No I don't see the 24 objects actually getting added to the `combinedModel` though, I just see them coming in separately initially in the `hArray` and `iArray`.  `NSLog(@"Self Combined Model %@", self.combinedModel);` prints out blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54856/discussion-between-danh-and-reez).

Comment: Hey Dan, any chance you can modify this answer for comparing 3 Dates?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028765/sorting-array-of-objects-by-date-into-tableview

Answer (score 3):

In your UITableViewDataSource methods, combine both arrays and use one or another accordingly:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // API1 + API2
    return hArray.count + iArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(indexPath.row < hArray.count) {
        // API 1
        YourAPI1Cell *api1Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourAPI1Cell"];

        // Do everything you need to do with the api1Cell
        // Use the index in 'indexPath.row' to get the object from you array

        cell = api1Cell;
    } else {
        // API 2
        YourAPI2Cell *api2Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourAPI2Cell"];

        // Do everything you need to do with the api2Cell
        // Remember to use 'indexPath.row - hArray.count' as the index for getting an object for your second array

        cell = api2Cell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Wain I'm trying to make it like a timeline per my comment above in the question, so that's why I wouldn't want to make different sections in the table, if thats what you mean.  Or were you meaning something else?

Comment: Getting a crash when I get around 20 cells scrolled "Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSRangeException, reason: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 20 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]"

Comment: And the `tableView` uses `API1` for the first 10 `tableViewCell`s, and `API2` for the next 20 `tableViewCell`s, then crashes. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I reconfigured per your code, and then also went to the storyboard to add a second prototype cell and identifier, and tried it out and thats where I got the previous crash/error.

Comment: In the console, `API1` has `10 objects`, `API2` has `20 objects`.  So I can't tell if its just loading all `API1` objects regardless of date before it loads any of `API2` objects.

Comment: What is the index you are using when getting your object from API2?

Comment: If you use `indexPath.row - api1array.count` that should not happen.

Comment: For API2, I've got `Data *dataLocal = [iArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - hArray.count];`  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: For API1, I've got `Feed *fLocal = [hArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` as listed in the Question above.  Let me know if you need any more info on it though, I'll definitely provide it.

Comment: Any suggestion for what else to try since different sections in table isn't going to work for this?  Thanks @Wain !

Comment: This should not be a big problem. Let's try again.
You have `hArray` for `API1` and `iArray` for `API2`.
The number of rows in the table is the sum of the length of both arrays.
Let's say `hArray` has 10 items and `iArray` has 20 items. The number of rows is 30 items.
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will use the first array to get the items from `0` to `9`.
For the items from `10` to `29`, you will use the second array, getting the items from `0 (10 - hArray.count)` to `19 (29 - hArray.count)` that should not raise any exception.
Are you getting items from any other array?

Comment: Please update your question with your current code that is not working, it will help on finding the bug.

Comment: There is no reason different sections wouldn't work. Each section doesn't need to have a header and if it doesn't then the user can't tell the difference...

Comment: @Wain but if the combined array is supposed to be sorted by time, then API1 and API2 need to be combined and not in two different sections.  You know what I mean?  Otherwise the 10th `tableViewCell` will be an `API1` result from 5 days ago, and the 11th `tableViewCell` will be an `API2` result from 5 hours ago.  Feel me?  Or am I still missing your point?

Comment: Ok, I see your issue. So you need to combine and sort the arrays into one and then reload (and your issue becomes the inability to refresh one source, you always need to tear everything down and reload both shources).

Comment: @brnunes I added all of my code (updated) so that it can be easier for you, thanks!

Comment: @Wain yup thats the issue.  Any ideas?  I updated the code in my question to show everything.

Comment: @brnunes I think maybe we are still talking about two different things, because I don't want items `0` to `9` to always be from the first array.  I want items `0` to `30` to be sorted by date, no relation to which `array` it came from.  So I would want items from `API1` to be able to be in `0` to `9` if their date was recent.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @brnunes maybe I'm still missing what you're getting at with your solution, if so just let me know, I'm slow catching on sometimes-

Comment: Any ideas on what I was missing in your answer that make it so I'm not quite getting it to work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your actual code works. These are steps you could do. I didn't try (don't know if its compiles), but you'll get the whole idea.

• I'll go with:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *contentArray;
```

Don't forget to initialize it: `contentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` before doing the WebService requests.

• In the blocks, I'll do:

```
[contentsArray addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult.array];
```

• You need to sort them by dates, so since we just need to add a method to sort them, but I don't know how are `Feed` & `Data` (objects in the `[mappingResult array]`), I'll let you do it. But I give you the main idea, since in the comments of the answer of @Wain, you said that the dates were `NSString`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//Do the dateFormatter settings, you may have to use 2 NSDateFormatters if the format is different for Data & Feed
//The initialization of the dateFormatter is done before the block, because its alloc/init take some time, and you may have to declare it with "__block"
//Since in your edit you do that and it seems it's the same format, just do @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter dateFormatter;
NSArray *sortedArray = [contentsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) 
{
    NSDate *aDate, bDate;
    if ([a isKindOfClass:[Feed class]])
        aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(Feed *)a.created_time];
    else //if ([a isKindOfClass:[Data class]])
        aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(Data *)a.published];
   if ([b isKindOfClass:[Feed class]])
        bDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(Feed *)b.created_time];
    else //if ([b isKindOfClass:[Data class]])
        bDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(Data *)b.published];
    return [aDate compare:bDate];
}];
```

• In the datasource method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`, do `return [contentsArray count];`

• In the datasource method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([[[contentsArray objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath row]] isKindOfClass:[Feed class]])
{
    Feed *feed = [contentsArray objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath row]];
    CellClassFeed *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"APICell1"];
    //Do your thing
}
else //if ([[[contentsArray objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath row]] isKindOfClass:[Data class]])
{
    Data *data = [contentsArray objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath row]];
    CellClassData *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"APICell2"];
    //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: The .h of `Feed` and `Data`, and especially showing the property you want to sort with should be a good idea. Another question is: Are Feed & Data that much different? Couldn't you regroup them inside one class?

Comment: I added a way to sort, or at least the main idea behind it.

Comment: Which line cause the error ? You copied my code, but I suggested that you do `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;` You do the init and setting the date format before requesting the data of your WebService. And you may have to comment the line in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of your previous `NSDateFormatter` since they became useless. And be careful. Since I just gave the main idea, you sort is in `sortedArray` not in your `contentsArray`.

Comment: Else, the issue may be `aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:(Feed *)a.published];`, you may have to replace it by : Feed *feedObject = (Feed *)a; aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:feedObject.published];` (ans do the same logic for the rest of the `if` tests. Plus, since `Feed` & `Data`
` seems quite different, it may not be a godd idea to "regroup them" as I suggested before in one class.

Comment: I figured out a couple things on this by adding some curly braces and then used `feedObject.published` and `dataObject.created_time`, so I'm not getting errors.  But two questions before it'll run are, I'm getting warnings next to each `aDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:feedObject.published];}` line saying `Incompatible pointer types sending NSDate to parameter of type NSString`?  And then `sortedArray` goes unused in your code so I'm not sure what to do with that either?

Comment: Ok. `published` (and the other one) is already a date. No need to use the date formatter.

Comment: Ok.  Any idea what to do with `sortedArray`?

Comment: It's your sorted array. You may replace what's in contentsArray (not sorted) with the elements in sortedArray (sorted)

Comment: So am I using `sortedArray` in the `tableView` dataSource parts instead of `contentArray`?  I just didn't see you put `sortedArray` anywhere in your example code other than where it was initially created, so I just wanted to make sure I was doing what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep a single property for the table data:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableDataList;
```

and have a method that is called in each success block:

```
- (void)addTableData:(NSArray *)items
{
    [self.tableDataList addObjectsFromArray:items];
    [self.tableDataList sortUsingDescriptors:...];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

to which you pass `mappingResult.array` and you fill in the sort descriptor information to get your timeline ordering.

Then your table view delegate / data source methods are really simple and just refer to `self.tableDataList`.

This is relatively similar to the answer from @Larme. From here I would get the item and check the class to decide how to configure the cell:

```
id item = [self.tableDataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([item isKindOfClass:[Feed class]]) {
    Feed *feed = (Feed *)item;
    ... // configure the feed cell
} else {
    Data *data = (Data *)item;
    ... // configure the data cell
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `id item = [self.tableDataList objectAtIndexPath:yyy];` instead?

Comment: It should, I had the wrong property name and the wrong method name, thanks @Larme

Comment: So far I have added the `tableDataList` property, added the method `addTableData` but what descriptor should I sort the date by inside of that method from what you see in my code?  I've never used those and am trying to find some info on it right now, but can't see anything that sticks out to me.  Please help if you can, thanks Wain!

Comment: The sort descriptor would use `published` or `created_time`, but both `Feed` and `Data` classes need to have a common method which returns an `NSDate` so that you can sort everything consistently

Comment: The comparator sort will work, but I'd modify the data classes to return a common date format so a sort descriptor could be used and the code would be cleaner. Then yes, my code is for the cell config.

Comment: Following progressive edits the 2 answers are basically the same, just written is a different style - the approach is the same. The point is to merge the 2 arrays, sort the contents and then check the type for how to configure the cells.

Comment: Am I using something like `[self.tableDataList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]]];`?  Like I'm just not quite sure what that part even looks like in my project when I'm trying to look up other examples and compare them ya know?

Comment: Yes, that code will be good *if* both of the classes have an NSDate property called date which is populated appropriately. Do they?