# 1 API source and 1 RSS source sorted by date in one table view

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, rss, restkit

This worked perfectly for me before:
[Get one NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795573/get-one-nsarray)

But **now, my second source is an RSS instead of API**.

I'm assuming I need to change `loadTwoWithSuccess` somehow, but I can't figure out how.

And then from there I will definitely need to update `sortCombinedModel` somehow per the new date for the second source.

Can you help me with this?  Thanks!!

Two async calls:

```
- (void)loadOneWithSuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                   failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

    NSString *apikey = @kCLIENTKEY;
    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"apikey" : apikey};
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1/n/?limit=4&leafs=%@&themes=%@", leafAbbreviation, themeID];

    [self.eObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:queryParams success:success failure:failure];
}

- (void)loadTwoWithSuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                   failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure {

    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://se.com/rss/c-b/"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"Success 2: %@", success);   
}
```

Load sources as single combined model:

```
- (void)loadMedia {

    self.combinedModel = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self loadOneWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult];

        // here's the trick.  call API2 here.  Doing so will serialize these two requests
        [self loadTwoWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

            [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult];
            [self sortCombinedModel];
            [self.tableView reloadData];

        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
        }];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Sort combined model:

```
- (void)sortCombinedModel {
    [self.combinedModel sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *dateA, *dateB;
        dateA = ([a isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)a).published : ((Data *)a).created_time;
        dateB = ([b isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)b).published : ((Data *)b).created_time;
        return [dateA compare:dateB];
    }];
}
```

New table view:

```
id model = self.combinedModel[indexPath.row];
if ([model isKindOfClass:[Feed self]) {
    Feed *feed = (Feed *)model;
    // configure cell with feed
} else {
    Data *data = (Data *)model;
    // configure cell with data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try to use RestKit for the RSS Feed inside of `loadTwoWithSuccess` because that seems to make more sense-