# Sorting Array of Objects by Date into TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nsarray

I used this answer to **sort 2** objects by date, and it **worked perfectly**: [Get one NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795573/get-one-nsarray)

I now need to **sort 3** objects by date, and **can't** quite modify what I have to **get that right**.

**All of the Articles from the API/RSS feeds will be sorted by date in 1 `tableView`.**

Here's what I tried:

```
- (void)sortCombinedModel {
    // All 3
    [self.combinedModel sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b, id c) {
        NSDate *dateA, *dateB, *dateC;
        dateA = ([a isKindOfClass:[FeedRSS self]])? ((FeedRSS *)a).pubDate : ((Data *)a).created_time : ((YaRSS *)a).pubDate;
        dateB = ([b isKindOfClass:[FeedRSS self]])? ((FeedRSS *)b).pubDate : ((Data *)b).created_time : ((YaRSS *)b).pubDate;
        dateC = ([c isKindOfClass:[FeedRSS self]])? ((FeedRSS *)c).pubDate : ((Data *)c).created_time : ((YaRSS *)c).pubDate;
        return [dateB compare:dateA compare:dateC];
    }];   
}
```

**Can you help me sort the 3 dates?**

---

*Additional info if needed:*

*I figured out how to modify this part - Have 3 API/RSS feeds coming in to one `NSMutableArray`:*

```
- (void)loadMedia {
    self.combinedModel = [NSMutableArray array];
    // Here's the #1
    [self loadOneWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult.array];

    // Here's the trick.  call API2 here.  Doing so will serialize these two requests
    [self loadTwoWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult.array];

    // Here's the trick.  call API3 here.  Doing so will serialize these two requests
    [self loadThreeWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

        [self.combinedModel addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult.array];

        [self sortCombinedModel];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
    }];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
    }];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"No?: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

*Here's what sorting 2 dates looked like previously:*

```
- (void)sortCombinedModel {
    [self.combinedModel sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *dateA, *dateB;
        dateA = ([a isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)a).published : ((Data *)a).created_time;
        dateB = ([b isKindOfClass:[Feed self]])? ((Feed *)b).published : ((Data *)b).created_time;
        return [dateA compare:dateB];
    }];
}
```

Comment: The old method should work no matter how many items are in the array.  When sorting an array, the comparator always takes two parameters.  It's job is to do pairwise compare of any two items.  The SDK sort method that calls it takes care of making all the right pairwise combinations.  If its not working with the existing (2 param) method, then there's some other problem.

Comment: Its working perfectly with the 2 param method you posted in the original question (the method I posted that says "Here's what sorting 2 dates looked like previously:")

Comment: The thing I can't get to work, is the first part of code I listed in this question under "Here's what I tried:" that uses 3 params.  As you can see, I added a `dateC`.

Comment: I modified your `loadMedia` method correctly now that I have 3 items.  I could not figure out how to modify your `sortCombinedModel` correctly even though it's gotta be something small I'm just missing I'm sure.  Any ideas what I'm missing or how to modify it?  Thanks!

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. I'll add an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator must always take two values to compare, but it wants to check if those two values are one of three types.  Add the following to the public interfaces defined in FeedRSS.h, Data.h and YaRSS.h:

```
- (NSDate *)sortDate;
```

In each of the implementations, add a method that returns the right date property to sort on for the class, so, e.g.

```
// FeedRSS.m
- (NSDate *)sortDate {
    return self.pubDate;
}
```

Same idea for Data.m (return self.created_time), and same for YaRSS.h, return whatever date that object has that you want to sort on.  Now your comparator is like this:

```
- (void)sortCombinedModel {
    [self.combinedModel sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *dateA = nil, *dateB = nil;
        if ([a isKindOfClass:[Feed self]]) { dateA = ((Feed *)a).sortDate; }
        else if ([a isKindOfClass:[Data self]]) { dateA = ((Data *)a).sortDate; }
        else if ([a isKindOfClass:[YaRSS self]]) { dateA = ((YaRSS *)a).sortDate; }

        if ([b isKindOfClass:[Feed self]]) { dateB = ((Feed *)b).sortDate; }
        else if ([b isKindOfClass:[Data self]]) { dateB = ((Data *)b).sortDate; }
        else if ([b isKindOfClass:[YaRSS self]]) { dateB = ((YaRSS *)b).sortDate; }

        return [dateA compare:dateB];
    }];
}
```

This works if the array contains only the three kinds of objects you expect.  If you always want to sort this way, an even tidier approach is to implement compare: in each of those classes, in each one checking if the param is one of the other two types.

Comment: This makes total sense.  Going to try it now!

Comment: Works great!  Except its sorting them by least recent date, instead of most recent date.  Do I need to just change the last line `return [dateA compare:dateB];` to `return [dateB compare:dateA];`?

Comment: Yes, just swap the order

Comment: Is there any small line of code you'd recommend to put in there if 1 of the 3 API/RSS feeds doesn't load so that the table view will still load?  Like if API1 doesn't load or website is down, API2 and API3 will still sort into a Table View.  Right now the whole Table View doesn't load if all 3 APIs are not up and working.

Comment: It will be easier to understand (and for others to help) if you open a new question. Include the current code that's not working and paste a link to it here.  Should be very doable to work even when one api fails.

Comment: Opened a new question, would be elated if you'd take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051247/load-view-controller-data-even-if-one-source-doesnt-load